# GDB Python APIs: Doesn't .parse_and_eval() make .cast() and .dereference() redundant?

Tags: python, c++, c, gdb

I am not able to understand the utility of the two GDB-Python APIs, `Value.cast()` and `Value.dereference()`. I feel `gdb.parse_and_eval()` can do exactly the same thing that these 2 guys do ( and more ).

For example, I can achieve `Value.cast("int*")` with `gdb.parse_and_eval('(int*)Value')` and I can achieve `Value.dereference()` with `gdb.parse_and_eval(*Value)`.

Specifically I have seen people use `.dereference()` to dereference a `struct` pointer like `some_struct_ptr.dereference()['some_var']`. Even here I feel `.dereference()` is not needed at all. `some_struct_ptr['some_var']` produces the exact same output.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

`parse_and_eval` does not always do exactly what you want.  Unlike some other operations, it is exposed to the user's current language setting, and sometimes other things like `set print object`.  And, if you already have a `gdb.Value` from some other computation, using `parse_and_eval` means that you must convert it to a string first -- but this can be a pain if pretty-printers are involved, instead for safety you have to convert it to a `long` and then to a string.

It is true that `dereference` is not needed if accessing a member via a pointer.  This is a gdb quirk that got exposed via `Value`.  Perhaps for the better.

While I still think it is best to use the `Value` API, it isn't always possible.  For example there is no way to assign this way; and there are some other holes as well.

That said, you can write your code however you like.